# How do I get the length of shortest route by arcpy after solve the NA

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I use arcpy.na.MakeRouteLayer build a layer, and use arcpy.na.AddLocations add two stop points, and use arcpy.na.Solve get the shortest route.
But how can I get the length of the shortest route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, the code is shown on the next picture.
**UPDATE:**
[image]